# Identify observation(s) within a variable containing noninteger values

Tags: stata

I am trying to run a `statsby` command and I keep getting a `group_id: factor variables may not contain noninteger values; an error occurred when statsby executed regress` error. It seems that the variable defining the groups (i.e. `group_id") contains noninteger values and this is causing trouble.

How can I identify the noninteger cases so I can deal with them? Or is there a more holistic approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float test
  1
  2
3.1
  4
  5
end

tab test if test != round(test, 1)

       test |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
        3.1 |          1      100.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          1      100.00
```

Other similar solutions could use `int()`, `floor()` or `ceil()`.